# Electrical terminology in the breaker box

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I'm trying to understand how the breaker box is wired so I can turn off power in some part of my house. In my country (Spain), lights are on a separate circuit(s), and usually entire rooms are controlled by separate breakers. But here I'm puzzled by the nomenclature. I'm attaching an image of the labels so you can help me understand the meaning of them.

1. Liv / Kit LTS: Is liv "living room"?  What's LTS?
2. FAU: I know this from another question that it's the air blower in our unit.
3. Kit |O|: no idea.
4. Comp: no idea.[image: Unknown labels in my breaker box]

Comment: Have you tried turning off breakers to see what they control? "LTS" could easily be "lights," "FAU" is likely (as you found) "Forced Air Unit," "Kit" seems to be "Kitchen" in general, so it might be a dishwasher or oven. The easiest thing to do is flip breakers and see what happens.

Comment: Are you sure this is your breaker panel? This looks A LOT like a North American 120/240 split-phase panel, particularly the 2-pole breaker at the bottom.     Yours will certainly be 230V (400V across 2 phases, if you have two phases, which is not common).  Those breakers are all wrong for that, correct for US, and I see UL and CSA listing marks and no EU marks (though CSA does list EU devices).

Comment: Harper, he writes, "In my country (Spain) . . ."  He did *not* write, "This is in my country (Spain) . . . " So you are correct that this is in the US, but how could you write, "Are you sure this is your panel?"

Comment: @JimStewart you're right, I missed that.  The reason I aked is that we sometimes see askers fail to take a photo of their own and grab a similar looking one off Google image search thinking it's all the same...

Comment: The first step is as Hari said: turn everything on/plug something into every outlet and flip off the breakers one at a time to see what turns off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering your questions in turn:

1. Liv/Kit LTS. indeed means "Living Room/Kitchen Lights"
2. FAU could be a small on-demand water heater (FAUcet according to Harper) or it could be a Forced Air Unit (air handler) as you are thinking
3. The circle with two lines through it is the *de facto* North American standard electrical plan symbol for a duplex receptacle, so that line is short for "Kitchen Receptacles"
4. Comp. most likely is short for a trash compactor if you have one.

Comment: #2 is FAUcet, it's an on demand water heater.

Comment: Im going with FAU is Forced Air Unit (a blower or swamp cooler)

Comment: FAU looks like 30A with a handle tie. 30A @ 240VAC is more likely a heater than a non-A/C cooler. Odd that one breaker is "common trip" and the other isn't, but the handle tie spans them.

Comment: My panel also has a G.D.O. What's that?

Comment: It may be "Garage Door Opener." Going to check now...

Comment: @GabrielStaples -- yeah, GDO = Garage Door Opener

Comment: Confirmed! GDO = Garage Door Opener. I tested it and saw that earlier today now. Thanks. I wish electricians didn't write in code so much. For them to save 1 minute extra of writing on my panel when they first installed it, I've lost 3 hrs researching online and walking up and down 4 stories to repeatedly check things, since my breaker box is on the 4th floor and my garage is on the 1st floor (it's a condo).